# set animation to MaterialSearchView suggestions in android

Tags: java, android, android-animation, searchview

set animation to MaterialSearchView suggestions in Android. in my materialsearchview when we try to search something it comes a list of suggestions I need to animate this suggestion at the time of opening. this is the way I add suggestions

```
SuggestionList[i] = (json.getString("name")+" ,"+json.getString("location_name"));
MaterialSearchView .setSuggestions(SuggestionList);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far for animation them. to be honest your question is not quite clear to me. like how animation? please elaborate your question.

Comment: i need to add an animation to material search view suggestions